# gcloud datastore: Can I filter with IN or Contains operator?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

I am a new bee with the Datastore gCloud. And I want to filter in an entity called Score all the scores that have relation with a list of companies. My entity is formed as follows:

```
{
    "company_id": 1,
    "score": 100, 
}
```

I have several entities with different company IDs. I tried to filter using the query.add_filter command but got the error ValueError:

> ('Invalid expression: "IN"', 'Please use one of: =, <, <=,>,> =.')

The reason for the error is very clear to me, but I have not found anything in the documentation on how to run filters with IN or CONTAINS, in addition to types other than those listed in the above error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filters operators you seek are not supported by the datastore. The only supported ones are listed in [Filters](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#filters):

> The comparison operator can be any of the following:
>
> ```
> Operator                  Meaning
> EQUAL                     Equal to
> LESS_THAN                 Less than
> LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL        Less than or equal to
> GREATER_THAN              Greater than
> GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL     Greater than or equal to
> ```

Some of the client libraries may offer some equivalents, but with limitations. For example the standard environment GAE-specific `ndb` library (not usable in your context) offers such support. The example from [The != and IN Operations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in) can be useful as you can implement it in a similar manner in your code:

> Similarly, the IN operation
>
> ```
> property IN [value1, value2, ...]
> ```
>
> which tests for membership in a list of possible values, is
>   implemented as
>
> ```
> (property == value1) OR (property == value2) OR ...
> ```

Comment: The lnked page now lists IN as one of the available operators but the error `ValueError: ('Invalid expression: "IN"', 'Please use one of: =, <, <=, >, >=.')` is still returned.

Comment: With the Python client, I got 
ValueError: ('Invalid expression: "IN"', 'Please use one of: =, <, <=, >, >=.')
with google-cloud-datastore~=2.5.1
But it worked with version 2.7.0, so you should probably upgrade your client libraries.