# Get only selected object from array of objects gcloud datastore

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have this structure in my gcloud datastore

```
"data": {
"obj": {
"added_time": "new Date().toUTCString()",
"person_id": 13,
"places": [{
    "place_id": 12,
    "place_name": "First Place",
    "place_type": "1",
    "fruits": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "orange"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "apple"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "place_id": 15,
    "place_name": "secondPlace",
    "place_type": "1",
    "fruits": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Grapes"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Banana"
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
 }
 }
 };
```

I want to query on added_time,person_id and place_id

This is my composite index

```
indexes:
- kind: persons
  properties:
  - name: obj.person_id
  - name: obj.added_time
  - name: obj.places.place_id
```

I tried this query

```
  const query = datastore
.createQuery("persons")
.filter("obj.person_id", "=", 13)
.filter("obj.places.place_id", "=", 12);
```

This is working but it gives me all other places as well.
For example in this query I should get only place object with place_id 12 but I am getting another object with place_id 13 which should not come.

1)How can I get only one object?

2)Is it possible to use 'in' operator in datastore like `places.place_id in (12,13)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a (simple) query for the `persons` kind, so results will be `persons` entities, which include the entire `places` array.

The only way to obtain a `persons` entity with just a single place in the `places` array is to do a [projection query](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries). Technically you'd obtain an array of such `persons` entities - one for each matching place, but since you're also filtering by `place_id` the array will only contain one element.

You'll need to pay special attention since you'd also be projecting on array properties, see [Projections and array-valued properties](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#properties_with_array_values_can_behave_in_surprising_ways). And also check the projection-related [Restrictions on queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#restrictions_on_queries).

No, filtering doesn't have support for an `IN` operator, see [gcloud datastore: Can I filter with IN or Contains operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582670/gcloud-datastore-can-i-filter-with-in-or-contains-operator/49605194#49605194)